# Save file upload state in post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a file upload control in the page

```
  <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

On click of saving the files should get upload, My problem is there are other server-side events which may get executed after file upload is selected once other server side events are executed file upload control selection is reset.Is there some other way to save the state of file upload selection.

Comment: You will probably need to do that manually, e.g. hold its state to another control such as a `<asp:Hidden>`.

Comment: If the workflow is like this, first the user selects the file upload control files then he executes all the server side event after all he changes the file upload files again since the state is saved first will it cause any issues, Should we check to see whether the files save in hidden input is same as the file upload selected one.